# Axiom of Specification

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I am reading Halmos's Naive Set Theory. I am really enjoying though I never read such a book. But there are some things that I am unable to grasp. Notably in the second chapter after stating the axiom of specification he presents a condition that (x does not belong to x). After that he uses this condition by say that {x belongs to A: x does not belongs x}. What I don't understand is that how can we talk about an element belonging to itself ? and what does it mean ?

Comment: See [Russell’s Paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/)

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3288477/what-was-the-definition-of-set-that-resulted-in-russells-paradox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is simpler to approach it in terms of *predicates* (expressing properties of objects). See original Russell's formulation [*The Principles of Mathematics* (1903)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Principles_of_Mathematics)]:

> Among predicates, most of the ordinary instances cannot be predicated
> of themselves, though, by introducing negative predicates, it will be
> found that there are just as many instances of predicates which are predicable of themselves: predicability, as is evident, is predicable,
> i.e. it is a predicate of itself. But the most common instances are negative: thus non-humanity is non-human, and so on [i.e. the predicate *humanity* applies to human being and not to predicates, and thus it does not apply to itself; on the contrary, the predicate *non-humanity* is not a human being, and thus applies to itself]. The predicates which are not predicable of themselves are, therefore, only a selection from among predicates, and it is natural to suppose that they form a class having a defining predicate.

Here we can see the basic ingredient: the [Comprehension principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification#Unrestricted_comprehension) stating that every predicate (expressed by a formula $\varphi$ of the language of sets) identifies a unique set $S$, i.e. the set (or class) defined by the predicate "to be a predicate that cannot be predicated of itself".

---

Regarding "not belonging to itself", we can try with the following example.

We know the *natural* numbers: $0,1,2,\ldots$ and we have the set $\mathbb N$ of all naturals, such that $0,1,2 \in \mathbb N$.

We have that $\mathbb N \notin \mathbb N$: the set of all naturals is not itself a natural number.

Assume now that we can define the set of non-naturals:

> $\overline {\mathbb N} = \{ x \mid x \text { is not a natural number } \}$;

we have that this set is not itself a natural, and thus:

> $\overline {\mathbb N} \in \overline {\mathbb N}$.

Comment: I thought of approaching the question by looking at '$\in$' as a relation but it leads to a circular dependency as the definition of a relation makes use of '$\in$' itself. Do you know if there is some independent definition of the "belongs-to" symbol?

Comment: In Halomos's words 'belonging is primitive (undefined) principal'

Comment: @СССР - In set theory $\in$ is part of the language: it is a binary predicate and it is the "basic property" of sets: sets have elements and are in turn elements of other sets. In set theory *relations* are specific type of sets: a binary relation is a set of *pairs*.

Comment: Doesn't it then answer the question of what $x \in x$ means? If "belongs-to" symbol is defined as a basic property of **sets**, then $x \in x$ implies that $x$ is assumed to be a set (not element), otherwise $x \in x$ would not be a valid notation at all.

Comment: @СССР - $\in$ is a symbol of the language and thus $x \in x$ is a formally correct formula, like $x=x$. Only with **Regularity axiom** we can prove that "circular chains" of sets like $(x \in y) \land (y \in x)$ are ruled out.